# Reference style issue using the elsarticle template

Tags: cross-referencing, elsarticle

New to this community - so bear with me. I recently submitted a manuscript for Bioresource Technology, Elsevier, using their tex templates. I was requested to use the elsarticle-template-2-harv.tex template and model2-names.bst reference style. So I did, but had it rejected due to incorrect reference list style...(???) They request the Harvard method (authoryear, e.g. (Aida et al., 2010)) and the reference list to be first alphabetically ordered - and then the list to be numbered.. However, I get no numbers in list, which was the rejection point.

What I have:

Aida, T.M., Shiraishi, N., Kubo, M., Watanabe, M., Jr., R.L.S., 2010. Re-
action kinetics of d-xylose in sub- and supercritical water. The Journal of
Supercritical Fluids 55, 208-216.

Akhtar, J., Amin, N.A.S., 2011. A review on process conditions for opti-
mum bio-oil yield in hydrothermal liquefaction of biomass. Renewable and
Sustainable Energy Reviews 15, 1615-1624.

What I need:

[1] Aida, T.M., Shiraishi, N., Kubo, M., Watanabe, M., Jr., R.L.S., 2010. Re-
action kinetics of d-xylose in sub- and supercritical water. The Journal of
Supercritical Fluids 55, 208-216.

[2] Akhtar, J., Amin, N.A.S., 2011. A review on process conditions for opti-
mum bio-oil yield in hydrothermal liquefaction of biomass. Renewable and
Sustainable Energy Reviews 15, 1615-1624.

Anybody who experienced the same issue, and anybody who knows how to work around this issue? I obviously already contacted the Elsevier support, but had no reply..

Thanks in advance!

/Thomas

Comment: In my view, providing numbers in front of the formatted bib entries is utterly redundant if authoryear-style citation call-outs are in use.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.