# How can I add numbers to my author-year natbib (elsarticle) reference list to confrorm with guide for authors?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, natbib, elsarticle

I know this question is a duplicate of [Reference style issue using the elsarticle template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248269/70739), but that question was closed 4 years ago for lacking details and clarity. Since I need to resubmit within 10 days, I post this one with more detail and an MWE instead of trying to reopen the old question

I am trying to format the reference list using `elsarticle` class to comply with Bioresource Technology's (BITE) Guide for Authors.

It is not as easy as it ought to be using elsevier's LaTeX template since BITE for some inexplicable reason wants to use Harvard (authoryear) style both in the text and reference list, but preceed each reference in the reference list by a number, like a numbered list.

The Guide for Autors specifically states:
**References in the list should be placed first alphabetically, then numbered chronologically.**

This style is not present among elsevier's bibtex style files and I am wondering how this can be achieved?

I am currently using the standard `plainnat.bst` style file with `authoryear` option set in the `\documentclass`, as in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat.bst}
\begin{document}
These citations: \citep{Feynman1963118,Dirac1953888}.
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

mybibfile.bib:

```
@article{Dirac1953888,
  title   = "The lorentz transformation and absolute time",
  journal = "Physica ",
  year    = "1953",
  author  = "P.A.M. Dirac"
}

@article{Feynman1963118,
  title   = "The theory of a general quantum system interacting with a linear dissipative system",
  journal = "Annals of Physics ",
  year    = "1963",
  author  = "R.P Feynman and F.L {Vernon Jr.}"
}
```

The above MWE generates

[image]

The journal wants these two references to be preceeded by [1] and [2] (and so on when adding more references), respectively. How can this be achieved?

`elsarticle` class uses `natbib`, but I can not figure out how to tweak it to make the reference list a numbered list as well. It is a really strange request from the journal.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412250/70739.
Adding `\setcitestyle{numbers}` before defining the `\bibliography` achieves just what I asked for.
Sorry for not searching well enough beforehand.